# Pi Putty Resolution

Tags: raspberry-pi, resolution, putty

So I've tried editing the config to disable_overscan=1, but despite that and several reboots, my Pi only uses the top third of a Putty terminal screen, if I resize the terminal, it continues to use the the original size. Anyone know how to force the Pi to use the entirety of the size of the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the hdmi_force_hotplug=1
like specified in this post https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=18585  or elsewhere ?